# Is it ok to use the same vars on consecutive loops in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

If you have a loop set up like

```
for (var i=0,  t=myArray.length; i < t; i++)
```

once that loop is complete, is it ok to use the i and t vars in the next non-nested loop within the function?

I've been numbering my nested loops differently like

```
for (var i2=0,  t2=anotherArray.length; i2 < t2; i2++)
```

but also doing the same for non-nested loops. I'm wondering if there's a need?

I ask, as Flash doesn't like it when you use the same vars, regardless if the second loop is not nested.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Yes. It is ok to use the `i` and `t` vars in the next *non-nested* loop.

Comment: While it is safe to do so, I think it's not good style since it's a little confusing to see the same counter used in different loops. If loops are nested, you almost certainly don't want to do it. Bottom line though is it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` `i` or `t` is declared in the scope where the loop is in.

Javascript uses "Hoisting".

So,

```
for (var i=0, t=myArray.length; i < t; i++) // first loop
```

is equal to:

```
var i,t;
for (i=0, t=myArray.length; i < t; i++)
```

So, when you use the same variables next time in a *non-nested* loops, like this:

```
for (var i=10, t=myArray.length; i < t; i++) // second loop
```

the `i` and `t` are already hoisted and hence you are just doing something like this:

```
var i = 0;
i = 10;
```

### So it is okay to use `i` and `t` vars in the next *non-nested* loop.

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Normally loop variables aren't used for anything other than doing calculations within the loop.

Even though the variable is available outside the loop, normally it isn't used.

Sometimes you might set another variable to the exit value of a loop variable.

```
 for(i=0;i<max;i++){
   ....
   if (some exit condition that leaves the loop early){
           //should assign value here instead of outside the loop
           exitvalue = i;
           break;
   }
 }

 //exitvalue = i; //can assign the value of i here (try to avoid this)
```

Therefore it is usually quite safe to reuse loop variables.